# baseboard heat noise

Tags: plumbing

I have oil heat with cast iron baseboard heat. One of them has noise in it & last year I had to bleed it multiple times to get the air out of the line. The only problem with doing this was that our boiler air tank had to be refilled this year when it was serviced. The noise is back again in the same location. Any suggestions on how to once & for all get rid of the air in the line?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the noise is air in the line, rather than pipe expanding/contracting as it heats and cools or simple water turbulance?

Is there a manual bleeder valve you could use to release any trapped air, as there is on older radiators? If so, there are automatic bleeders (basically float valves) which could be installed. You'd want to do that at the highest point in the loop, since that's where any air will wind up.

My house also has an device installed at the boiler end of things which lets bubbles escape from the system there, before they can circulate farther.